# How to Put this strength meter bar to an object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
#pragma strict

var strengthAmount : float = 0.0F;
private var maxStrengthAmount : float = 100.0F;
var guiSkin : GUISkin;
var barSprite : Texture2D;
var powerButton : GUITexture;
function Update () {
for (var touch : Touch in Input.touches)
{
if (strengthAmount >= 100.0F)
{
    strengthAmount = maxStrengthAmount;

    // Do stuff here
}
else if (strengthAmount < 0.0F)
{
    strengthAmount = 0.0F;
}

 if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary && powerButton.HitTest(touch.position)){
    strengthAmount += 1.0F;
}        
else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && powerButton.HitTest){
    strengthAmount = 0.0F;
}
}
}
function OnGUI()
{
GUI.skin = this.guiSkin;
GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(Screen.width / 8, Screen.height - 167.5F, 150         
(strengthAmount / maxStrengthAmount), 31), barSprite);
GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width / 8, Screen.height - 167.5F, 150, 31), "Strength");
}
```

Here is my strength meter bar code, but I want to put it on an object that when I release the button, the object will be thrown away? I am new to Unity3D so please help me how to make a script on that or help me directly thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a JS script, paste this script and save it. Create a game object, select it, on the inspector click on the button Add component. Then find your script and add it.

Then create another script that has the following:

```
Update() //this is C#
{
if (GetKeyUp(KeyCode. /*here find the key code of the button that you want to release*/ )
Destroy(this); //if you want to destroy the object
}
```